# How can I change screen brightness on a Macbook through Java?

Tags: java

Is this something within the realm of possibility? 
I know I might need to do something like this if absolutely necessary.

```
String cmds[] = {<command for changing brightness>};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds);
```

Comment: What are you asking exactly? Are you asking if such a command exists? Or how to execute it through Java?

Comment: Did you google? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34884/how-can-i-dim-the-screen-from-terminal   Just use that approach with Runtime.exec (or better, ProcessBuilder).

Comment: How I could do it through java.

Comment: Though, yes I did google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to pass commands to the terminal through Runtime to interface with the screen's brightness.